# Is safe supplier bank details(bank name,account number) stored in custom table?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment

I want to store supplier bank details in my custom table for transfer amount to their accounts.Is it safe store supplier bank details in database table ?
Is it need encryption for bank details ? if need encryption which encryption and all bank details data need encryption ? What I do in this situation ? please hint me please

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

In order to store any kind of bank details you would need to be fully PCI compliant. Even then, I believe there are restrictions on exactly what information you can store (you can't store a CVE number from a CC card for example). The fact that you are asking the question makes it highly unlikely you are fully compliant as becoming compliant can be an involved process that requires stringent internal business processes to be in place on top of the technical requirements.

Comment: It means that I need record only bank account number and bank name.Can I store only Bank name and bank account ?

Comment: My real intense about this record is if I have bank name and account number of suppliers so I can transfer amount to suppliers account manually not online.